# JUnit test timing in Eclipse

Tags: java, junit

I have JUnit 3 setup on Eclipse Helios. I created a test case to add 1 million users through a web service and test the result.

I don't quite understand JUnite timing, the result (on JUnit output):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testrun name="UserRegistrationTestCase" project="TestCases" tests="1" started="1" failures="0" errors="0" ignored="0">
  <testsuite name="testcases.UserRegistrationTestCase" time="8880.946">
    <testcase name="testCreateUser" classname="testcases.UserRegistrationTestCase" time="8880.946"/>
  </testsuite>
</testrun>
```

The time says on the JUnit display: `8,880.946 s`. What does that mean? Does that display in seconds (whereas in the XML the `time="8880.946"`)?

Is `8880.946` (in XML) in milliseconds? If not, how would I configure Eclipse JUnit to allow time to display in milliseconds (The reason I ask is because I initially added 1000 users and the result came to `13.593s`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timing is always in seconds. Not sure how to change it, and with that large a number, why would you want to?

If you want the time in milliseconds, you can of course move the decimal 3 places to the right.

Comment: With milliseconds, we want to calculate ways to calculate `latency` in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

This is the format in which the time is present in xml:

```
seconds.ms
```

So in your case it is 8880 seconds and 946 millis