# Simple Method of Outputting jUnit Timings to Consumable Format

Tags: performance, junit, capture, timing

I'd like to capture the timings from my jUnit tests into some format that I can pull into excel or csv. Is there a tool or even a simple way to do this through injection to do this?

I've seen [jUnitPerf](http://www.clarkware.com/software/JUnitPerf.html), but this does not include any output, and also requires code to create sets of tests, which is far more elaborate than I am thinking.

(investigated the following questions without finding the answer)

- [JUnit test timing in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165800/junit-test-timing-in-eclipse)
- [Capturing timing data from Junit tests on Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545234/capturing-timing-data-from-junit-tests-on-eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to write your own runner with a custom listener:

```
public class TimingRunner {

  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
    RunListener listener = new TimingListener();
    junit.addListener(listener);

    List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
    for (String each : args) {
      classes.add(Class.forName(each));
    }

    Result result = junit.run(classes.toArray(new Class[0]));
    system.exit(result.wasSuccessful() ? 0 : 1);
  }


  private static class TimingListener extends RunListener {
    private Map<Description, Long> tests = new HashMap<Description, Long>();

    @Override
    public void testStarted(Description description) {
      tests.put(description, System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    @Override
    public void testFinished(Description description) throws Exception {
      Long startTime = tests.get(description);
      if (startTime != null) {
        long runTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime.longValue();
        System.out.println(description + ", " + runtime + "\n");
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void testRunFinished(Result result) throws Exception {
      System.out.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Pass the class names of the tests you want to time to TimingRunner's main.